# periodic noise detection in image's frequency domain

Tags: image-processing, fft, noise

Since I'm learning frequency domain and I'm really curios about this topic, I'm trying to solve a problem (that I have already solved it using morphology [detecting lines by their thickness]) in frequency space (I know it's possible). here it is the picture:
[image]

I'm trying to build a notch filter to remove lines frequencies.
[image]

I'm not sure but I think peaks on horizontal and vertical line are the noises (paper lines) and I've tried so many ways to remove them and none of them works. I'm not looking for a code and just wanna learn how it works and some tips to solve the problem. I really appreciate your kind contribution in advance.

**Results after removing peaks:**

Now I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in detecting peaks (I've no idea what kind of peaks I'm looking for)

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes. what is the point of inverting it? does it really matter in fft of a binary image? can you elaborate what is trough in fft and how can I find them?

Comment: I added result of removing peaks

Comment: What is the find_peaks call, is this a numpy thing or did you write it?  Did you check what the actual prominence of the peaks are, and whether there's anything left after you remove that?

Comment: are you removing all of the peaks in the grid, or only the ones along the axes?  Plot the FFT afterward

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment about the troughs, I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: I'm updating post for requested plots. find_peaks is a scipy function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: The peaks are equally spaced in both dimensions, like the lines are equally spaced in both dimensions: https://i.imgur.com/Kdp3p2U.png  Find the distance between the peaks in each direction and then remove everything at those intervals

Comment: is this plot representing part of my image? how you get that?

Comment: @Abolfazl74 it's just `log(abs(scipy.fft.rfft2(image)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with a simpler one-dimensional case first and then work your way up to two dimensions.

If you slice one row of your graph paper:

```
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load image as pixel array
image = image.imread('7ocEX.jpg')

image = 255-image  # Invert
plt.plot(image[42])
```

You can see it's an (intermittent) impulse train:

[image: Impulse train slice]

The first is at pixel 23.5 and the last is at pixel 672, so you know the period of the train is (672-23.5)/11 = 58.9545 pixels/cycle, and so the frequency is:

700 pixels/image / 58.9545 pixels/cycle = 11.8736 cycles/image

If you plot the Fourier transform:

```
F = fft.rfft(image[42])
plt.plot(abs(F))
```

you see peaks at harmonics of 11.9 pixels, as expected:

[image: Fourier transform peaks]

If you then remove those peaks from the spectrum and inverse transform, the impulse train will be removed, too.  You know their frequency, and you know that harmonics are integer multiples of the fundamental, so you can eliminate them from the spectrum without any peak finding.

Comment: I really appreciate it sir. I've no idea which one is the best answer... both of them are awesome

Answer (score 3):

Even though the lines are periodic, but they are closer to a train of impulses than a harmonic, so they will leak to many harmonics.

The best feature to distinguish the lines from the rest is that the lines are either horizontal or vertical, vertical lines are represented at the horizontal borders of the FFT, horizontal lines are represented at the vertical borders of the FFT.

Here is the result if you filter out (set to zero) the first four and the last three lines and column of the FFT.

[image: Example]

### Answering a comment

Here you can see the frequency domain `log(fftshift(abs(fft2(image))))`, before and after filtering.

[image]

### Bonus

Just because maybe you would be interested, you can apply morphological filters and get a result like this :D

[image: morphological filtering]

### Offtopic

Yesterday the the author said this
[image]

He accepted the answer, but after unaccepted
[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. I finally found main problem of my algorithm couple of hours ago but still there a problem. I built a notch filter and made a mask with filtered frequencies. multiplying mask (same size with fft) with image's fft suppose to remove(make zero) all paper lines but its giving me this https://i.imgur.com/bUzZb94.png. (I'm quite sure there is trick that I don't know is this type of filtering). one more thing, you said "the first four and the last three lines" did you find them without shifting fft?if not thats a new way an I would be glad to hear more explanation about it.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty good. please add your fft plot (peak spots) to mark it as the answer of my question.

Comment: Added all the code the code

Comment: Yes sir I'm not looking for code I'm just trying to learn. I'll code it my self. I was asking you to show your spectrum(or any visual representation of fft) that you used for detecting peaks. Thank you again for answers

Comment: So in summary, I am not searching for peaks, I am relying on the assumption that the lines are vertical/horizontal and based on that I already know where their energy will be concentrated in the frequency domain.

I am not using fftshift as well.

Comment: Yeah if you measure the distance between the lines in pixels, you should be able to predict the positions of all the peaks

Comment: so you mean these peaks on x,y vector are not representing lines in spatial domain?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKzeJ.jpg

Comment: "I already know where their energy will be concentrated" well! that's what I wanna learn! how you know that.

Comment: @Abolfazl74 It's the same principle as taking the FT of an impulse train in one dimension.  Are you familiar with that?  If you graph a single pixel row of your grid paper it will be an impulse train.

Comment: The lines can be regarded as a plane wave, the horizontal lines would be waves propagating vertically, so the horizontal component of the wave vector must be (nearly if not perfectly aligned) 0.

Comment: Check this for some details about wave vector.

Comment: Ok I finally understand that (freq domain was really hard to understand self-taught tho). I think my notch filter was the problem and my detected peaks as line were fine(of course with your great explains) .

Comment: I've no idea why you took that personally but I still think your answer is very helpful and your explanation really help people like me to understand the issue and I appreciate it. the second answer (that was submitted after your answer) mathematically explain the problem and it tell me a lot of stuff about the problem and I think when somebody like me is trying to understand how frequency filtering works that mathematical example is very helpful. I'm really sorry if changing the answer bothered you sir.

Comment: It is ok, your choice, I just decided to keep a record of this

Comment: @Bob I upvoted this, for the record :D

Comment: Thank you. I know you are new. I sincerely wish that it was of some use, also I pointed something I think is much better than FFT filtering in there.

Remember that the people who is writing here are volunteers, the only thing they get back is some gratefulness, and reputation. Your promise sounded like that client that receives the deliverable and says, can you just make this, this and that, then I will pay you. Yes, you are the owner of the question, but this does not make you the boss.

Comment: I don't have the intention to flag this as a misconduct. This is what I was saying about taking personally. I will deal with it personally :)

Thank you again, bye